# How to access secondary constructor parameter outside constructor block in Kotlin

Tags: constructor, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and working through the tutorials that are available.
However now I seem to have a problem with a secondary constructor:
Parameters declared in the primary constructor can be accessed in a function,
but when I try to do this with a parameter from the secondary constructor I get an error: Unresolved reference:nbr

The code:

```
class Test(_name: String) {
val name: String = _name

constructor(_name: String, _nbr: Int) : this(_name) {
    val nbr: Int = _nbr
}

fun printNameAndNumber() {  
    println("Name: $name")
    println("Number: $nbr")
}
```

}

It is clear to me that I am doing something basically wrong but who can tell me what?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`nbr` should be a variable, because in this specific case it is optional:

```
class Test(_name: String) {
    val name: String = _name
    var nbr: Int? = null

    constructor(_name: String, _nbr: Int) : this(_name) {
        this.nbr = _nbr
    }

    fun printNameAndNumber() {
        println("Name: $name")
        println("Number: $nbr")
    }
}
```

Comment: While this will work, Tamas' and DVarga's answers are better in most circumstances.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters of the primary constructor are not available in member functions. Fields are. Fortunately Kotlin has a short syntax to make primary constructor parameters member properties right away.

What do you expect `nbr` to be when constructed using the primary constructor? I suggest you to swap your constructors, so it's clear what are properties and what are just parameters:

```
class Test(val name: String, val nbr: Int) {
    constructor(name: String) : this(name, 0)

    fun printNameAndNumber() {  
        println("Name: $name")
        println("Number: $nbr")
    }
}

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    Test("Péter").printNameAndNumber()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`name` is accessible because it is a member.

`nbr` is not accessible because it is a local (immutable) variable inside the secondary constructor.

If you declare `nbr` as member: putting `val nbr: Int` for example below the `val name` line, it will be accessible, however it will not compile if `nbr` is defined as immutable (`val`).

A simpler structure would be:

```
class Test(_name: String, _nbr: Int = 0) {
    val name: String = _name
    val nbr: Int = _nbr

    fun printNameAndNumber() {
        println("Name: $name")
        println("Number: $nbr")
    }
}
```

or even simpler

```
class Test(val name: String, val nbr: Int = 0) {
    fun printNameAndNumber() {
        println("Name: $name")
        println("Number: $nbr")
    }
}
```

If you want your `nbr` member as nullable, you couldgo with the suggestion of @gil.fernandes.